# How to store domain objects in the right way

Tags: android, inheritance

I have two classes, the first one is called `Product` and basically holds all the available products and their attributes loaded from the database. The other class is called `OrderProduct`, extends `Product` and have two more attributes: quantity and date. OrderProduct is used as a temporary object holding the information about current order. At the end of the order, order object is saved to the database. My question: should I follow my current structure or design it that way that OrderProduct will not extend Product class and will just hold id to access specific product and have these two additional attributes: quantity and date? Or is there better way how to do that?

Product:

```
package domainLayer;

public class Product {

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private String type;
    private int price;
    private String status;

    public Product(int id, String name, int price, String type, String description, String status) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.price = price;
        this.status = status;
    }

    public Product(Product product){
        this.id = product.getId();
        this.name = product.getName();
        this.description = product.getDescription();
        this.price = product.getPrice();
        this.status = product.getStatus();
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setPrice(int price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public int getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }
}
```

OrderProduct:

```
package domainLayer;

import java.util.Date;

public class OrderProduct extends Product {

    private int quantity;
    private Date date;

    public OrderProduct(int id, String name, int price, String type, String description, String status, int quantity, Date date) {
        super(id, name, price, type, description, status);
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.date = date;
    }

    public OrderProduct(Product product, int quantity, Date date){
        super(product);
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.date = date;
    }

    public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    public int getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }

    public void addQuantity(int quantity){
        this.quantity += quantity;
    }

    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would not do that. `OrderProduct` is not a real subclass so it should not be a subclass of Product.

Instead create an OrderProduct with getters for product, quantity, date etc.